# Unable to get `naturalWidth` of an img tag in Firefox Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have a testcase where i have to verify broken website logo image, for that I'm using below code :

```
WebElement logo = getDriver().findElement(By.locator);
assertTrue(logo.isDisplayed(), "Failed", "Success");

if (logo.getAttribute("naturalWidth").equals("0")) {
        assertTrue(false, "FAILED :" + logo.getAttribute("outerHTML") + " is broken.",
                "Success");
}
```

The same code working fine in Chrome browser bu failing in Firefox. 
Also i have printed the value of `naturalWidth` its 300 in chrome (as expected) but 0 in Firefox (FF `v60.0.1` and geckodriver `v0.21.0`). also tried with wait as well before checking the condition.

Why this happening in Firefox only ?

Also I've tried alternate solution

```
String url = logo.getAttribute("src");
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
if (String.valueOf(con.getResponseCode()).equals("200")) {

    assertTrue(true, "FAILED :",
                "Success" + logo.getAttribute("outerHTML") + "exists at server");

} else {
    assertTrue(false, "FAILED :" + logo.getAttribute("outerHTML") + " is broken.",
                "Success");
}
con.disconnect();
```

But getting intermittent issues.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @RajKamal, Sorry I can't

Comment: @NarendraR was it consistent when running with chrome? Did you try adding a sleep after WebDriver#get and see whether it works? Looks like by the time logo.getAttribute is called the image itself is not loaded.